# Bootstrap JS stops working after route change in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am using Angular 5, and Bootstrap 4. I have bootstrap installed as an npm module, and it is set up in my angular-cli scripts and style portions. I essentially only have two routes in this application. A login route, and a table view route.

```
scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "libs/pjd-design-system-core/dist/scripts.min.js"
    ],
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "theme.scss",
    "styles.scss",
    "libs/pjd-design-system-core/css/pjd-icons.css"
  ],
```

I have noticed that when I leave the login route, and go to the table view route the JS portion of bootstrap no longer works. I have tested this by taking the dropdown component code from the bootstrap 4 website and pasting it into my login component and my table view component. In the login the dropdown opens, but in the table view the dropdown does not.

Other relevant information.
Angular Version: 5.2.0
Angular-CLi Version: 1.7.3

**Edit:**
What I expect to happen is once I change routes that any bootstrap element that requires javascript will still function. What currently happens is that once I change routes, and a new component is loaded (read once I leave the landing page, and go to the table view page) any bootstrap element that requires javascript to function (such as a dropdown menu) no longer functions (the dropdown will no longer open when clicking on it). Currently I am receiving no errors.

Included router module code

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PayEstimateFormComponent } from './pay-estimate-form/pay-estimate-form.component';
import {SigninComponent} from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth-gaurd.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/payEstForm', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: SigninComponent},
  {path: 'payEstForm', component: PayEstimateFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: "No longer works" is not a helpful description of your problem. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: There might be issue in somewhere else part of your code can you also upload your router module code?

Comment: @TheHeadRush I have updated my question with some more information, and hopefully have painted a clearer picture of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Unless you need to reinvent the wheel, i'd take a long look at a library like `ng-bootstrap`: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: @GWilliams I am also having the same issue for bootstrap validations, side panels etc. Did you find any workaround?